# What size difference is there between the PSP 1000, 2000 and 3000 for applying Skin Stickers?

Tags: psp

I've been looking at some Sword Art Online Skin Stickers but it says that they are meant for the PSP 3000, from the looks of the images the only difference I see between the 2 models is that the metal ring around the back is slightly thinner

So I'm wondering, with the PSP 1000, 2000 and 3000, what differences are there with size that could affect how a Skin Sticker is applied?

[Here's a Link to one Skin Sticker](http://www.amiami.com/top/detail/detail?gcode=CGD2-53255).

Comment: pretty sure the 2000 and 3000 are the same form factor; the 1000 (original) model certianly isn't; the rear has a pronounced "butt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the PSP screen size and general layout of the buttons stayed the same during the *x000* iteration, there are noticeable differences between the models:

**PSP-1000 vs PSP-2000**
[image: PSP-1000][image: PSP-2000]

- Speaker holes moved from lower side to upper side
- Button placemenet changed
- Different UMD slot, UMD switch on 1000
- Headphones port moved, different power connector
- IR port on 1000
- 1000 is thicker

There's a radical physical diffenece between the 1000 and the later models, therefore a cover intended for the PSP-1000 would probably not fit the later models and vice-versa.

**PSP-2000 vs PSP-3000**
[image: PSP-2000][image: PSP-3000]

- Added microphone hole on 3000 next to PSP logo
- Start, Select and Home button changed shape
- [Ring around the PSP logo on UMD cover is thinner on the 3000](http://sweet17th.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/psp-3000-31.jpg)

Other than that (and different internals), PSP-2000 and 3000 are pretty much the same, I would assume a cover made for either will fit the other model, but it'll require some modifications on the bottom part, to fit the different button shapes and microphone hole, and will look different on the back cover because of the different ring thicknesses.

Comment: Gotta add PSP GO and PSP Street versions too.

Comment: I skipped PSP GO because it's radically different in form factor from any other version, so I assume no skins will be "cross-compatible" with it.
PSP E-1000 might look only slightly different than the 1000/2000/3000 models, but the different speaker/switch/UMD cover of it will prevent skin compatibility. I focused on the most popular models. Feel free to edit GO/E1000 info into my answer if you wish to.