# Will a 200x or 300x PSP case fit a PSP e1004?

Tags: psp

I'm looking for a crystal case for a PSP e1004 but I haven't found such a thing. Will a case for 200x and 300x model match? I know i have to check speaker placement, eventually I can make a little hole by myself, i'm just asking about shape.

EDIT:

I took a risk and bought case for 200x model. Regardless of almost identical size and shape, 200x case does not fit e100x console.

Comment: I've seen that thread before, but it did not answer my question.

Comment: It has links to information regarding dimension and provides the additional information about what, if any, alterations you would need to make for a perfect fit. The information you asked for is something the Internet is rife with (device dimension), to a point that it almost seemed lazy to even ask. Even though I flagged it I also answered in the event moderators felt by flag was not well placed and because it wasn't hard to give and it would be trite to forego something so easy to gather.

Answer (score 1):

From an archived Sony website for the [PSP e100X](http://www.sony.co.in/local/product/psp+e1004):

> Approx. *170 x 23mm x 74mm*

From Lifewire website for the [PSP 200X](http://Dimensions:%206.7%22/170%20mm%20wide%20x%202.9%22/74%20mm%20high%20x%20.9%22/23%20mm%20deep)

> Approx. *170 mm x 23 mm x 74 mm*

From TechPopIN website for the [PSP 300X](http://techpopin.blogspot.com/2012/09/sony-playstation-3004-psp-3004.html)

> Approx. *169mm x 19mm x 71mm*

In terms of dimension, the e100X and the 200X are identical but you'll have to inspect the layout and component placement to make sure the case is interchangeable. [This answer to a similar *Arqade* question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117085/what-size-difference-is-there-between-the-psp-1000-2000-and-3000-for-applying-s?rq=1) offers information one can glean this information fairly well.